# Use settings file in azure dev-ops pipeline maven task to resolve dependencies

Tags: azure, maven, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, maven-settings

I need to run a maven task in a Azure dev-ops pipeline using a settings file (used to resolve some dependencies from an internal repository). I can get the file using the "DownloadSecureFile@1" task and then I can copy it to the default working directory. Inside a bash task I am able to build the project using

```
mvn -s settings.xml verify
```

However I need to run the maven goal using the "Maven@3" task (the test coverage and SonarQube analysis configuration is done with it). If I specify the settings parameter

```
          - task: Maven@3
            displayName: Build and run tests
            inputs:
              mavenPomFile: "pom.xml"
              # mavenOptions: "-s settings.xml -Xmx512m $(MAVEN_OPTS)"
              mavenOptions: "-Xmx512m $(MAVEN_OPTS) --settings settings.xml"
              javaHomeOption: "JDKVersion"
              jdkVersionOption: "1.11"
              jdkArchitectureOption: "x64"
              publishJUnitResults: false
              goals: "verify"
              sonarQubeRunAnalysis: true
```

(MAVEN_OPTS is just a variable defining the local repo with -Dmaven.repo.local) the task fails with this error:

[image: error]

Maven is installed, without the settings parameter it will fail because it couldn't resolve the dependencies. The same thing happens if I use "-s" instead of "--settings".

Using the "ArtifactoryMaven@2" task I am able to execute the goal, but it doesn't seem to have all the options of the "Maven@3" task, and I couldn't figure out how to get it to use a specific repo for caching the dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your task definition, you defined the `-s settings.xml` at **mavenOptions** field.

This is the root cause of this issue.

You need to define the settings.xml at **Option** field.

For example: `options: '-s settings.xml'`

```
      - task: Maven@3
        displayName: Build and run tests
        inputs:
          mavenPomFile: "pom.xml"
          options: '-s settings.xml'
          mavenOptions: "-Xmx512m $(MAVEN_OPTS)"
          javaHomeOption: "JDKVersion"
          jdkVersionOption: "1.11"
          jdkArchitectureOption: "x64"
          publishJUnitResults: false
          goals: "verify"
          sonarQubeRunAnalysis: true
```

Refer to the doc: [Maven task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/maven?view=azure-devops)